# Unix shell delay filename expansion

Tags: environment-variables, zsh, zshrc

I have a (java) software project with source file is several directories.

If I do the following in my .zshrc file:

```
J=dir1/*.java dir2/*.java dir3/*.java ...
export J
```

Then I get errors that the environment is too large

Normally I use a makefile tree that compiles one directory (package) at a time but sometimes the relationship changes are too messy so I do:

```
javac $J
```

To recompile the whole lot.

Question: Can I do something to quote the list, like

```
J="dir1/*.java dir2/*.java dir3/*.java ..."
export J
```

So that the environment is small but have the variable expands the filename list when it is used.

I know I could something like

```
javac `eval ls $J`
```

but I was hoping the invocation could still be simple.

Comment: Did you mean `J=(...)`? Right now, you are trying to invoke a command whose name depends on the expansion of `dir2/*.java`.

Comment: Do you get any errors with `javac dir1/*.java dir2/*.java dir3/*.java ...`? The allowed size of the environment (which consists of environment variables and command-line arguments) is an OS-specific limit.

Comment: I get no size limit with the javac. I assume that an expanded list in an environment variable AND and expanded list in the command breaks the limit but if the environment variable is small the one expansion shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Probably; so don't use `export`; there's no reason to do so.

Comment: OK, not using $J in any scripts won't be too much problem, I can expand them. It feels like a work-around rather than a solution but I can live with it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
J=(dir1/*.java dir2/*.java dir3/*.java ...)
```

(no `export` needed, since `.zshrc` is sourced). With `J` set, you can simply run

```
javac $J
```

or more explicitly (without or without the braces)

```
javac ${J[@]}
```

Whether you need quotes depends on which shell options you have enabled, but they aren't necessary by default in `zsh`.

Comment: J=(list of directories/*.java)
echo $J
Lists all the files, so clearly the '*' has been expanded already.

Comment: Yes, that's required. Unless  you have a special version of `javac`, it expects each file to compile as a separate argument. Your only option is to run `javac` multiple times, each time on a subset of the desired files.

Comment: Not true. I can always run
    javac dir1/*.java dir2/*.java dir3/*.java ...
So as a fall back I can make a script especially to do that, but sometimes I also use grep or wc $J

Comment: Is this running under Windows or some form of Unix?

Comment: Sorry I thought the reference to .zshrc made that clear - its unix, Mac OS to be precise.

Comment: If `javac dir1/*.java dir2/*.java dir3/*.java` works by itself, then the export is probably the problem. `javac` isn't expanding the globs; the shell does that *before* `javac` is run. Exporting `J` and expanding it basically takes up twice the space: one half for the arguments, the other half for the (ignored) value of `J` in the command's environment.